# How to check if database credentials are correct in Java?

Tags: java, sql, credentials

I have these two methods. I can't seem to get it to work. The first method initializes the database connection and the second runs an other GUI after the log in procedure. I want to check if credentials are correct first before calling the GUI Class. Anybody has any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

```
    public void getDBConnection() throws SQLException{
    userid = usernameF.getText();
    password = passwordF.getText();
    OracleDataSource ds;
    ds = new OracleDataSource();
    ds.setURL(jdbcUrl);
    conn = ds.getConnection(userid,password);

    if(conn){
    System.out.println("Connected Successfully to Database. User: " + userid);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong Data");
    }

}



    private void loginbox_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    try {
        getDBConnection();
    } 
    catch (SQLException f) {
        status.setText("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD");
        }



    GUI guid = new GUI();
    guid.setVisible(true);
    guid.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    System.out.println(userid + " " + password);


}
```

Comment: @BeginnerJava: programming terms like "database connection" and "GUI" are NOT code. Please stop incorrectly formatting them as code in suggested edits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getConnection` returns a [java.sql.Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), your if statement should be using the `isValid` method of that to see if it's connected so for example that line could be `if (conn.isValid(5)) {` (where **5** is the maximum number of seconds to wait)

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a statement that has no effect to see if a connection works.

```
// for example
select 1 from dual;
```

Connection pools use this strategy to check if a connection is valid before returning it.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/jdbc_connection_pools.html for a verify statement overview (Table 127-1 Default Test Table Name by DBMS).

Answer (score 0):

Return true or false from getDBConnection() method on the basis of connection logic 
then use the value in login method and perform the action of activating GUI or not